# rest_client gem is deprecated and will be removed from RubyGems. Please use rest-client gem instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rubygems, rubymine

Trying to get started with API testing using rest client in ruby, however, hitting issue after issue, any how hopefully someone will be able to help.

I am using RVM ruby-2.0.0-p648

I have rest_client External Lib files, however, when I try to run my script I get the message: WARNING: The rest_client gem is deprecated and will be removed from RubyGems. Please use rest-client gem instead.

Process finished with exit code 0

So in my require I changed to rest-client and installed: gem install rest-client, however it is not showing in my external Libraries?

Anyone hit this issue before with a solution?

Also using rubymine.

Comment: I just fixed this by updating gem file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you figured this out, but just to be clear...

You want to update the `Gemfile`.

Change

`gem 'rest_client'`

to

`gem 'rest-client'`

and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Yea thats what I did, dunno why it took me so long to figure out. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Speedychuck it's okay, I had the same problem with my latest project, I searched Google for about two hours until I figured it out lol